# Issue loading a page with Realtime Database contents

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I recently set up a small web page using Firebase; say:
https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/.

It uses a Realtime Database to provide contents to the visitor.

It usually works, but it happens that the page does not load as it should. Specially after being let for a while without being touched.
To load the page, it is necessary to click the refresh button.

Why is that happening and how could I avoid it?

For reference, here the relevant code of the index.html page.

```
<table id='ItemTableList'></table>
<script>
  const dbReference = firebase.database().ref('ItemList');
  let output = document.getElementById('ItemTableList');
  output.cellSpacing = 17;

  dbReference.on('value', function(listItem) {
    output.innerHTML = ''; // We clean the list.

    listItem.forEach(function(tutoItem) {
      let itemLnk = document.createElement('a'),
      itemR = document.createElement('tr'),
      itemD = document.createElement('td');
      const itemVal = tutoItem.val(),
      itemText = document.createTextNode(itemVal.name),
      lineBrk = document.createElement('br');
      itemLnk.appendChild(itemText);
      itemLnk.href = itemVal.url;
      itemD.setAttribute('style','text-align:center');
      itemD.style.backgroundColor = '#FEFEDB';
      itemD.appendChild(itemLnk);
      itemR.appendChild(itemD);
      output.appendChild(itemR);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. It'shard to say why this happens without more details. Is this something you can reproduce in a site that we can have a look at? If not, are there any error messages showing in the JavaScript console when this happens?

Comment: Well, I would also say the code is fine; it works 99% of the time. The issue only happens if I leave the page alone for a while. For example when I wake up in the morning and go to visit it. After a reload or visit with a different browser the problem is gone. I haven't look at this point for any error message in the web console. If you want to have a look at the site and try, this is the address: https://tutorama-20796.firebaseapp.com/.

Comment: Thanks for that link. How do I know whether the page is working or not?

Comment: If you see a list appear, it is working. If not, it is not working and you will need to hit the refresh button to make it work. Or otherwise stated, if you only see ".... a collection of tutorials ....", then something is still missing, but if you see ".... a collection of 36
tutorials ...." (the number may vary if I add items) then all is good.

Comment: I left the site open overnight, and everything still seemed to work when I came back just now. If you can give me steps to reproduce the problem, or relevant messages from a run where the problem occurs, I can have another look.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I also had a look this morning. I first opened using Safari and all was right, then I opened with Firefox and the list did not appear, I had to refresh. So that could be a browser issue.... A bit more trials tends to show that the problems appears when using a Firefox non-private windows. I hope these bits of information will be useful.

Comment: I tried to open the Web Console in Firefox, to see if I could catch some error message when the page first loads. I got this:
"Paused on exception
TypeError: self.OffscreenCanvas is not a constructor". It doesn't look to me much related to what I am doing. But what I can say is, when I refresh the page though I see the same kind of message again, the list shows up.

Comment: That indeed sounds like an unrelated message. Sorry I can't be of much help here. The best chance that we can help, is if you provide a [minimal, complete/standalone reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now there's just too much going on in the link for me to troubleshoot efficiently.

Comment: OK. Thank you, I need to look at what I can do.

Comment: Were you able, at least to see, the problem I mentioned with the information I provided? Using Firefox.